# Python merge two dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I would like to return a dictionary where values are lists sorted by descending length of values.

ex.

```
data = {'r': [4,3],'t': [4,5,6], 'n': [1,6]}
```

must give

```
data = {'t': [4,5,6], 'r': [4,3],'n': [1,6]}
```

Then, after this first sort, I would like that keys be sorted in alphabetical order for values of same length, as with

```
data = {'t': [4,5,6], 'n': [1,6], 'r': [4,3]}
```

Is there a way?

Comment: This question has been asked several times, see for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]dict+sort).

Comment: But if you decided that it's okay to return a list like `[('t', [4,5,6]), ('n',[1,6]), ('r',[4,3])]` then people here can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't sort a regular Python dictionary. They have no order. You can, however, use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = {'r': [4,3],'t': [4,5,6], 'n': [1,6]}
tuples = data.items()
tuples.sort(key=lambda pair: len(pair[1]), reverse=True)

ordered = OrderedDict(tuples)
```

And the result:

```
OrderedDict([('t', [4, 5, 6]), ('r', [4, 3]), ('n', [1, 6])])
```

`lambda pair: len(pair[1])` is your key function, so given a `(key, value)` pair, it returns the length of the values. You can also use `(len(pair[1]), key)` to sort alphabetically if two pairs have the same value length.

Comment: I think the OP would want `pair[0]` or `pair[0].lower()` to be the second element.  (I used `(-len(pair[1]), pair[0].lower())` as the tuple, and no reverse.)

Comment: @DSM: I wasn't sure if the key name or the value was going to break ties. I'll just leave that part off then

Comment: The way I read the "alphabetical order" sentence it's by length of value and then alphabetical on key, but I could be misreading it (and it's likely enough anyway that there are other yet-unspecified criteria..)